# Idempotency in Google Cloud Function HTTPS triggers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Most firebase cloud function trigger function signatures include a context object which has an `eventId` property.

Looking at the documentation, this doesn't seem to be the case for HTTPS-triggers.

Is it safe to assume that calls to HTTP functions will only trigger once per request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jack's answer is mostly correct, but I'll clarify here.

The documentation on execution semantics [is here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec).  To be clear:

> HTTP functions are invoked at most once. This is because of the
>   synchronous nature of HTTP calls, and it means that any error on
>   handling function invocation will be returned without retrying. The
>   caller of an HTTP function is expected to handle the errors and retry
>   if needed.

There is no guarantee that an HTTP function is executed *exactly* once.  Some executions may fail before they reach the function.  This is different from all other (background) types of function that provider at least once execution:

> Background functions are invoked at least once. This is because of
>   asynchronous nature of handling events, in which there is no caller
>   that waits for the response and could retry on error. An emitted event
>   invokes the function with potential retries on failure (if requested
>   on function deployment) and sporadic duplicate invocations for other
>   reasons (even if retries on failure were not requested).

So, for background functions to be 100% correct, they should be idempotent.

If you want to retry failed HTTP functions, the client will have to perform the retry, and in that case, you may want that HTTP function to be idempotent as well.  The client will have to provide the unique key on retry, in that case.

Note that it's not possible to mark an HTTP function for internal retries.  That's only possible for background functions.

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS functions will only trigger once compared to background functions that have a at least once delivery guarantee.

*(I cant find the docs where I read it. If I find it i will update the question)*

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait to see if someone from Google can confirm, because I got this reply from their support when asking this question: "No, all functions (background and http) may trigger more than once. Events are delivered at least once, which means that rarely, spurious duplicates may occur. So we suggest to always make your function as idempotent."

But he also wrote this about eventId: "...it looks like this is currently unsupported . doesn't seem to be documented. It could be possible to implement, however we don't have this available out of the box..."

Comment: Both Jack's answer and the one you got from support are correct: Cloud Functions (then you enable retries) have an "at least once" guarantee. In rare instances they may trigger more than once, and you should code your functions to deal with this. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#semantics_of_retry

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Both Jack's answer and the one I got from support can't be correct at the same time? Only once is not the same as at least once in my book. Or do you mean that HTTP-triggers will only trigger once, while the other triggers may trigger "at least once"? Thanks

Comment: "all functions (background and http) may trigger more than once". If you have a specific problem, I'd recommend posting the code that reproduces that problem. That's typically a lot more productive than trying to wrest meaning from the words you were given in various places.

Comment: See my answer for a more detailed explanation of what's going on here.  HTTP triggers don't have any built-in retry semantics. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Hmm... good point. So the answer from support probably also should've pointed that distinction out.